# Radio Button Dynamically in ASP.net using html.append

Tags: asp.net

I am adding values to html table from a database. What I want is to attach a radio button with each row such that if the user selects a row to be deleted he may do so. I am getting the value of my radio button as vehicle_syskey from the following code and not the numerical value that the variable  stores. Below is my code. Please tell me how I can achieve this. Thanks in advance.

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
        html.Append("<table border=1");

        //append headers

        //Populating a DataTable from database.

        <--Some Relevant Code Present Here>

        int vehicle_syskey = 0;
        string gm_ymm = null;
        foreach (DataRow row in oemTable.Rows)
        {
            html.Append("<tr>");

            vehicle_syskey = Convert.ToInt32(row[0]);
            html.Append("<td>");

            html.Append("<input type='radio' name='veh_key' class='my_button' value=vehicle_syskey ");
            html.Append("</td>");
            html.Append("<td>");
            html.Append(vehicle_syskey);
            html.Append("</td>");

            gm_ymm = Convert.ToString(row[1]);
            html.Append("<td>");
            html.Append(gm_ymm);
            html.Append("</td>");

            html.Append("<td>");


            //Another Query here

            foreach (DataRow row1 in vcdbTable.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column1 in vcdbTable.Columns)
                {
                    html.Append(row1[column1.ColumnName]);
                    html.Append("&nbsp;");
                }
                html.Append("<br>");
            }
            html.Append("</td>");

        }

        conn.Close();


        //Table end.
        html.Append("</table>");
        //Append the HTML string to Placeholder.
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });


    }
}




protected void match1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string val = Request.Form["veh_key"].ToString();
    Label l1 = new Label();

    l1.Text = val;
```

}

Comment: Learn to use webcontrols like `Repeater` or `GridView`, otherwise ASP.NET is not the best technlogy for you.

Comment: Do you have some help to extend here?

Comment: That's my suggestion. You can use a web-databound control like `GridView` with an `ItemTemplate` that contains those controls. You will get much more readable and maintainable code, compile time safety, don't need to care about viewstate or event issues and can add a `RadioButton`-control easily.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. I have explored that function. Just curious about this petty issue at hand.